# How to clone tag object with one get method?

Tags: javascript, html, xpath, svg, high-load

How to make clones tag object with svg image data in one page. Without many get methods to the server.
Sample of target page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
...
<object id="tg0" data="graph.svg" type="image/svg+xml" some_my_value="234"></object>
<object id="tg1" data="graph.svg" type="image/svg+xml" some_my_value="123"></object>
...
```

This sample get graph.svg with many get requests to graph.svg. First request shows result 200 all following shows result 304, but i need without the following once.

I found attr declare, but next code doesn't work wo attr data in #tg1.

```
<object declare id="tg0" data="graph.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
<object id="tg1" type="image/svg+xml">
    <param valuetype="object" value="#tg0">
</object>
```

With data attr, tg1 sends following get requests.

How can i do this in html, wo js. Is it possible to receive data from current page by relative uri ~like xpath.

graph.svg is self render image. It's can be worked in shadow root(it's not variant now) in div.
If can be one way - to use JS, how i can put XMLHttpRequesst result into the document in tag object?

Construction with elements like document.querySelector("..."). contentWindow/contentDocument/document/window/innerHTML = ... 
doesn't whork.

If js - need solution in pure js wo jquery and other frameworks. Firefox/Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found next solution, with frames DOMs

```
<object id="tg0" data="graph.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
<!--tg0 can be iframe-->

<iframe id="tg1" class="tg" type="image/svg+xml"></iframe>
<object id="tg2" class="tg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
<!--iframe Firefox and Chrome; object work in Chrome only-->    

<script>
    //some control to onload current page and #tg0

    //We can get data from tag object or iframe
    var tg0_TXT=window.frames['tg0'].contentDocument.rootElement.outerHTML;

    //Or get it from XMLHttpRequest
    var dataReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    //...
    var tg0_TXT=dataReq.responseText;


    var trgIframes=document.querySelectorAll(".tg");
    for(var ic0=0; ic0<trgIframes.length; ic0++) {
        //Select id, because window.frames works with id
        var idc=trgIframes[ic0].id;

        //Firefox doesnt want write in empty contentDocument in object
        //so #tg2 in Firefox is empty
        if(window.frames[idc].contentDocument) {
            //wo open/close scripts inside svg doesn't starts
            window.frames[idc].contentDocument.open(); 
            window.frames[idc].contentDocument.write( tg0_TXT );
            window.frames[idc].contentDocument.close();
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

And we can emulate declare inside svg with frameElement.declare and window.parent.frames["..."]

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is possible to create `clone` of `object tag` and you can use that `clone`.
Please follow the demo Link.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dYUUC/167/)**

Comment: It's send following request with result 304

Comment: Simple clone is not problem.
Problem - many requests to server, when object have clones.